# Clone Git Repository on Apache Server

Tags: git, apache, github

So I am trying to get an auto-deploy for my current website, I get to the part where I need to clone my repo onto the test server and I run into this problem:

1. Clone failed because the directory isn't empty.
2. It isn't empty because it has the .ssh folder and key in it but if remove the key then git cant access it.

Any ideas? Its an Apache server.

EDIT: The command I am using is - git clone git@github.com:[my git]/[my project] [web served directory]

Comment: Clone to a different directory?

Comment: Then the ssh key isnt recognized and the command returns "Host key verification failed"